# Reducing duplicates in a dictionary using LINQ in C#

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I'm trying to use LINQ to create a new dictionary from an existing one, removing duplicates in the process.

The existing dictionary is as follows:

```
Dictionary<LoaderConfig, List<ColumnInfo>> InvalidColumns = new Dictionary<LoaderConfig, List<ColumnInfo>>();

public struct LoaderConfig
{
    public string ObjectName { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LoadDate { get; set; }
    public string Load { get; set; }
    public string TableName { get; set; }
}

public struct ColumnInfo
{
    public string ColumnName { get; set; }
    public string DataType { get; set; }
    public int DataLength { get; set; }
}
```

What I want to end up with is a `Dictionary<string, List<ColumnInfo>>` where the key is the TableName attribute of the LoaderConfig objects and the list of ColumnInfo objects are unique for each TableName.

I started with this based on another post that I found:

```
var alterations = InvalidColumns
    .GroupBy(pair => pair.Key.TableName)
    .Select(group => group.First())
    .ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key.TableName, pair => pair.Value);
```

Which doesn't work because of the First().  I imagine there is a way to acheive this using LINQ extensions, I just need some help finding it.

Thanks!

Comment: Ouch. Why is `LoaderConfig` a `struct` ? I don't think it should be.

Comment: What is a duplicate for you? Is it the table name and column name? Is it all values of your `LoaderConfig` and `ColumnInfo`?

Comment: A duplicate would be a LoaderConfig.TableName and ColumnInfo object combination.

Comment: Why should `LoaderConfig` not be a `struct`?  I'm new to C#, coming from Java, so any tips would be appreciated!

Comment: It should have been a class. A struct is almost never called for. But changing it now might be too much work (Equality also changes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personaly I'll do something like this :

First create a IEqualityComparer for ColumnInfo (used by Distinct)

```
    public struct ColumnInfo
    {
        public string ColumnName { get; set; }
        public string DataType { get; set; }
        public int DataLength { get; set; }

        public class ColumnNameComparer : IEqualityComparer<ColumnInfo>
        {
            public bool Equals(ColumnInfo x, ColumnInfo y)
            {
                return x.ColumnName == y.ColumnName;
            }

            public int GetHashCode(ColumnInfo obj)
            {
                return obj.ColumnName.GetHashCode();
            }
        }
    }
```

Then the query :

```
        var colComparer = new ColumnInfo.ColumnNameComparer();
        Dictionary<string, List<ColumnInfo>> res = InvalidColumns
            .GroupBy(i => i.Key.TableName)
            .ToDictionary(i => i.Key, i => i.SelectMany(j => j.Value.Distinct(colComparer)).ToList());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  //untested
  var alterations = InvalidColumns
             .GroupBy(pair => pair.Key.TableName)
             .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, 
                           group => group.SelectMany(g => g.Value).Distinct());
```

An you have to work in a `.Distinct()` somehow.

**Edit** A Distinct() was indeed needed, added.

Comment: Edit your answer to:
var alterations = InvalidColumns
  .GroupBy(pair => pair.Key.MARSTable)
  .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, 
                group => group.SelectMany(g => g.Value).Distinct());

That worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dictionary<string, List<ColumnInfo>> alterations = InvalidColumns
    .SelectMany(p => p.Value, (p, col) => new { p.Key.TableName, col })
    .GroupBy(single => single.TableName, single => single.col)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Distinct().ToList());
```

`SelectMany` flattens the column lists, i.e it creates an enumeration of table names and single columns. This enumeration is then regrouped by table name.